# Why is my mysql database connection not working?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, npm

I am building a tool to help me insert data into a database. It worked completely fine and then I decided to change something because I found a bug.

I am using npm and have installed the 'mysql' package.

```js
import { createConnection } from 'mysql';

const databaseData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./database.json'));

const connection = createConnection(databaseData); 

connection.connect((error) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  console.log('Connected');
});
```

*I am using .mjs instead of the regular .js file extension, so that I can use import so that's not an issue.*

The problem is, that there are no errors, my code executes fine, but get no message into the console afterwards the status of the connection is 'disconnected' and my queries don't execute.

The content of the database.json file is:

```json
{
  "host": "w00c243c.kasserver.com",
  "user": "d0315584",
  "password": "PASSWORD",
  "database": "d0315584"
}
```

(PASSWORD is the actual password)

The code above is just a part of the whole index.mjs file, but the rest is working fine and thats the most important piece of code for this question.

I already tested a lot (databaseData is read correctly, there are no errors, the code is being executed, all works, only the connect((error) => { ... }); is completely ignored)

Comment: Does your console ever say 'Connected' ?

Comment: No my console, as I said, remains empty.

Comment: console.log(databaseData) and see if that is what you expect.

Comment: Please, show the content of your `database.json` and the thrown error, if any. Without those details we can't really help, the code looks alright

Comment: There is no error thrown and the database.json content is {
  "host": "w00c243c.kasserver.com",
  "user": "d0315584",
  "password": PASSWORD,
  "database": "d0315584"
} of course PASSWORD being the actual password

Comment: Given that your code *is* fine, even if the contents of `database.json` was wrong we would still expect an error.  I wonder if this file gets executed at all.

Comment: Yes, the file does get executed and works completely fine. The code I posted is just a small part of the whole file.

Comment: When I try your code I get `ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR` (as expected). How exactly are you running this?

Comment: @Tzimon if that's the case, you should try to isolate the problem further and make a file that actually lines up with what you are sharing here on stack overflow. Your code seems fine, so the problem might have to do with part of the code that we're not seeing.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with the code you actually shared here. If that does work as expected, try to see what the differences are.

Comment: Is your mysql server up? And can you access it through the port 3306?

Comment: So it actually works when I use the code in another file, but why?

Answer (score 0):

So my code was fine, but I did not get an error, because the error was thrown after I accedentally called `process.exit(0);`. Thank you all for your help though!

Comment: There's no need to post an answer in such a case; this question falls under the "not reproducible" category.